# Getting feedback on functionality and not code

Tags: discussion

I am writing a Template Engine, I don't really want my code reviewed, but I would like people to test it and give me feedback about what they think what I could add/remove/change. Would something like that be acceptable here?

Comment: That's basically asking for beta testers, not a review...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

I'm pretty sure that's outside the scope of what could be construed as on-topic here.

Comment: What about code review plus that?

Comment: @RyanNaddy, yeah, but I don't know that you'll get many people wanting to test it as you outlined.